# How to implement automatic reflection of direct SQL Updates of the underlying database, in an ActiveRecord in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, orm, stored-procedures, activerecord, triggers

I am new to Ruby on Rails and I have a (maybe naive) question:
I want to implement reflection of direct SQL Updates of the underlying database in an ActiveRecord (and finally in the generated html). By "direct updates" I mean updating the database bypassing the ActiveRecord methods, for example by MySQL console. I guess here MySQL triggers could be used that would call some stored procedure that would cause the appropriate ActiveRecord to be reloaded.

Is there some automatic handling of this scenario in ActiveRecord/Ruby on Rails ? Did somebody implement this scenario ? Can somebody recommend using other MVC frameworks to reflect direct changes in mapped databases ?

Answer (score 1):

I think the best solution is to use an AJAX routine in the browser that periodically checks for a "last_updated" timestamp in the app.

The app would also have a periodic routine that has some way of determining if the database has changed, either by looking at a table-record that says the last time the table was updated, or by asking the database for the maximum timestamp for an "updated_at" column. If the app sees that things changed it loads the new info and caches it for the requests from the browsers. If the app tells the browser that things changed then a subsequent request from the browser would be to update the changed info in the page.

You don't want user's browsers to initiate hits on the database, which is why they ask the Rails app. The rails app doesn't want to do it on demand by the browsers; It's acting as a limiter/bottleneck.